# time series terminology question

Tags: time-series, terminology

Suppose I have a time series $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{10}$. I apply the augmented Dickey Fuller test to my data an conclude the data are non-stationary with (say) lag = 2.

With lag = 2, the tested data are $x_3, ..., x_{10}$. My question is: Did I conclude that $x_1, ..., x_{10}$ are non-stationary, or did I conclude $x_3, ..., x_{10}$ are non-stationary?

Comment: All ten data points are used, not just $x_3, \dots, x_{10}$.  Consult the wikipedia page for the ADF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey–Fuller_test) and you can see that for a lag 2 test, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are included in the model formulation when $t=3$.

Comment: Also, like in other inferential tasks, you use the sample to draw conclusions regarding the underlying population/process, so it is really not the sample that is nonstationary (or not), but the underlying process is. Hence, there is no point to make the distinction in your post.